# Using javascript to close a foundation 4 dropdown button menu window

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am struggling with a JavaScript / jQuery issue. I am developing with foundation 4. I have a group of 5 buttons. Two of the buttons are [dropdown buttons](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown-buttons.html). When the dropdown button is pressed a window is presented with the dropdown options(links).

```
<a id="products" href="#" data-dropdown="prod" class="not_active_button_dropdown">Dropdown Button</a><br>

<ul id="prod" class="f-dropdown">
<li><a class="prod" href="index.php?info=basic">Basic</a></li>
<li><a class="prod" href="index.php?info=unifrost">Unifrost</a></li>
<li><a class="prod" href="index.php?info=teal">Teal-Sorb</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note: I created my own buttons classes with sass by mixin (`class="not_active_button_dropdown"`).

Now I developed a script that loads the php response into a div `#dropdownwrap`, changes the buttons so it highlights the current button that has been pressed.

```
<script style="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','a.not_active_button, a.prod', function(){

var href=$(this).attr('href');
var querystring=href.slice(href.indexOf('?')+1);

//get 
$.get('index_jq.php', querystring, processResponse).error(errorResponse);

//reset all buttons to not active
//normal button
$('a.active_button').removeClass("active_button").addClass("not_active_button");
//dropdown button
$('a.active_button_dropdown').removeClass("active_button_dropdown").addClass("not_active_button_dropdown");


//if it is a normal button make it active
if ($(this).hasClass("not_active_button")) 
{
$(this).addClass("active_button");
}


//if it is a dropdown button option link make it active 
if ($(this).hasClass("prod")) 
{
$('#products').removeClass("not_active_button_dropdown").addClass("active_button_dropdown");
//$('ul#prod.f-dropdown').close();
}

//slide down wrap
if ($('.dropdownwrap').is(":hidden")) {
      $('.dropdownwrap').slideDown();
    } else {
      $('.dropdownwrap').slideToggle("slow");
      $('.dropdownwrap').slideDown("slow");
    }



return false; // stop the link

});



function processResponse(data) {

 $('.dropdownwrap').html(data);

 }

function errorResponse() {
var errorMsg = "Your request could not be processed right now.";
errorMsg += "Please try again.";
$('.dropdownwrap').html(errorMsg);
}

</script>
```

I am not that experienced with JavaScript or jQuery. Anyhow the problem is the following:

```
//$('ul#prod.f-dropdown').close();
```

which is commented out above. Everything works fine, my data loads and the dropdown button highlights. The problem is that the foundation 4 dropdown button window does not close after the script executes. This is because (I am guessing) I return false to stop the link from executing. So I tried to close the window using the above commented out line. When I uncomment the line, the window closes but the return false does not execute, that is the link is not disabled, it goes to the link, i. e. `index.php?info=basic`. So it seems when I add the close window statement, return false does not work. I tried adding the line after return false, but it does not close the dropdown menu.

Comment: On further inspection the the line $('ul#prod.f-dropdown').close() is not causing the popup links to close when uncommented.

Comment: I tested a mouseleave function on the popup menu and I got a javascript error $(ul#prod.f-dropdown) does not have close method. I guess you cannot close a ul. Still trying to find a way to close popup.

Comment: Basically, I want to prevent the link from being acted on, but still want the popup window to close which return false is preventing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `return false;` not working is probably because there is some JavaScript error before it reaches that line. In this case, the error is calling `.close()` on something which does not have a `close` method. Instead, in order to call Foundation dropdown’s `close` method, you have to do something like the following:

```
$('#prod').foundation('dropdown', 'close', $('#prod'))
```

I guess there is a more elegant way to do this, but I found this to work. As a note, next time please post a minimal example on jsfiddle.net and link to it in your question. This makes reproducing your problem much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this can be quite annoying if there's a lot of them. I modified it to the following so they are all the same.  
<a href="#" class="button" onclick="$(this).foundation('dropdown', 'close', $(this).parent('.f-dropdown'))">Button</a>

Comment: Glad you suggested this approach. I couldn't find this documented anywhere in Foundation's v4.3.2 docs.

Answer (score 0):

You also need the data-dropdown-content attribute attached to the dropdown ul element.

Reference: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1831#issuecomment-15133817